# How to download a file from s3 using an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AMI image in which will be used for autoscaling, every EC2 instance that initiated from the AMI image,suppose to download some files from a s3 bucket, (They are all in the same VPC) the s3 suppose to be private(Not open to public).
How does this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways.  You could use the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) ([S3 Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)) or you could use the [SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) for the language of your choice.   You will also probably want to use [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to establish the credentials for accessing the resources.  The [CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is probably the quickest way to get up and running.

Comment: I actually read about the IAM, and I created one, for my ec2 instances(and attached it to them), so they already have the permission to access the s3, but I don't know how to download from s3,since I'm trying to automate the process, the SDK is not my option, im looking for some command line stuff.is there any built in linux command that I can use?(since i already have the permission) instead of aws cli?.....

Comment: AWS CLI commands can be used from the command line, and incorporated into shell scripts.